# How to exclude files from Clover report with Jenkins clover plugin

Tags: jenkins, clover

Does anyone know how to exclude files or directories using the Jenkins Clover plugin? The report it is producing includes files under src/test which is causing the results to be skewed.

btw. I'm using Ant to build the project (as opposed to Maven). Should I be adding the  block in the ant build file?

Answer (score 0):

http://jenkins-php.org/ was helpful for ant/jenkins setup. I did change the build.xml for phpunit. I added the following code to the phpunit exec task `<arg line="${basedir}/path/to/tests"/>`. To point only to my test folder which I have in the jenkins workspace.

To exclude folders/files from clover reports. You need to have a phpunit config file. Name it phpunit.xml.dist and keep that with your build file. There is more info and an example on the link above. Add the following code to the phpunit.xml.dist file. Hope this helps.

```
  <filter>
    <blacklist>
       <directory>PATH/TO/FOLDER/</directory> 
       <file>PATH/TO/File</file>
    </blacklist>
  </filter>
```

Link to phpunit confing file manual.
http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html